# Android - Allow XMLHttpRequest to local files on API Level < 16 possible?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, load, xmlhttprequest

For my Android Webview-App I have to do XMLHttpRequests to include html files stored in assets via jquery .load function. I found out that I can make this work by adding the following code I found here on stackoverflow in my android project:

```
web .getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

Eclipse tells me that this requires at least Api Level 16. Does this mean that it is only possible to do XMLHttpRequests with Api Level 16 and higher or does it mean that on lower versions it is supported by default?

Kind Regards,
Tobi

Answer (score 1):

Answered it by myself :)

Found this on developer.android.com

> The default value is true for API level ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1 and below, and false for API level JELLY_BEAN and above.